# Let $\tau \in S_n$ be the cycle $(1,2,...k)$ of length $k$, where $k \leq n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\tau \in S_n$ be the cycle $(1,2,...k)$ of length $k$, where $k \leq n$.

(a) Prove that if $\sigma \in S_n$, then $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}= (\sigma(1),\sigma(2),...,\sigma(k)).$ Thus,$\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$ is a cycle of length $k$.

My Attempt:

I am new to permutations so I am looking for help on how to prove this. I started by looking at example and I quickly realized that I don't understand what I am proving. Here is the example:

$\sigma=$
  \begin{array}(
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
    3 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 6 & 1 & 7
  \end{array}
$\tau=$
  \begin{array}(
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
    2 & 1 & 5 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 3
  \end{array}

$\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$ =
  \begin{array}(
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
    1 & 3 & 2 & 7 & 6 & 4 & 5
  \end{array}

So my first question is: in this example how does $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}= (\sigma(1),\sigma(2),...,\sigma(k)).$ ?

After explaining this to me, I would appreciate some hints on how to proceed with the proof.

Comment: $\tau$ is supposed to be a cycle of the form $(1,2,\dots,k)$ which it is not in your example.

Comment: thank you, now i understand that my example does not work

Comment: @YourAdHere can you give me an example of a cycle in that format?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comment, the $\tau$ from your example is not a cycle. A correct example would be

$$\tau=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
    2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7
  \end{array}\right)$$

which is the cycle $(1,2,3)$.

To prove the claim, ask yourself what happens if you plug in $\sigma(j)$ into $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}$, i.e. what is 
$$\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(j))$$ 
for $j=1,\dots,n$ ?

Since $\sigma:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ is a bijection these values completely determine $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}$.